Given an irrational number, construct the desired irrational number.
Here is an elementary analytic problem:
Construct a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that
$f(b)$, $f(b)+b$ and $f(b)+\sqrt{2}$ are  irrational numbers, for all irrational number $b$. In other words, given any irrational number $b$, construct an irrational number $f(b)$, such that both $f(b)+b$ and $f(b)+\sqrt{2}$ are irrational numbers.
The restriction is, I want to define such function constructively. In other words, I don't want to use the law of the excluded middle, and I don't want to use any forms of choice principles. Even the axiom of countable choice.
When I say $x$ is an irrational number, I mean $x$ is not a rational number. i.e, the assumption that $x$ is a rational number leads to a contradiction.
Since there are a lot of non-isomorphic definitions of $\mathbb{R}$ in constructive mathematics, solve this problem for
$\mathbb{R}^d$, the set of Dedekind real numbers. Even though I want a construction which works for all definitions of real numbers, the construction that only works for $\mathbb{R}^d$ would be appreciated.
I tried so hard to define such function. But I couldn't succeed. Maybe I didn't try enough but I wonder maybe such function doesn't exist at all. Is it true?
The only useful observation I have is that if such function exists, it must be continuous. This is because you cannot define a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ constructively which is not continuous. So, if you prove that such function cannot be continuous, then we cannot define such function constructively.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks.

What functions have you tried? There's a handful of simple functions that you should always reach for, when looking for examples or counterexamples...

Your sentence beginning "In other words" says something stronger than what was said before (which doesn't require $f(b)$ to be irrational for irrational $b$). Can you clarify please.

There are a lot of functions we can define explicitly that are not continuous. EG $f(x) = 0 $ if $x$ is rational and $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is irrational.

why not take $f(x)$ identically $0$?

@lulu: that was my immediate reaction, but the sentence beginning "In other words" adds in the extra requirement that $f(x)$ is irrational when $x$ is irrational.

@RobArthan  Yeah...I guess that is one of the conditions?  Seems odd to slip it in like that.  Anyway, that certainly makes for a more interesting problem.

@CalvinLin: your examples are not constructive in the sense that you can define a Turing Machine that will take a constructive representation of $x$ (as some kind of stream of rational inputs, e.g., a decimal representation) and will calculate from that a representation of $f(x)$ as a stream of the same form. A function that can be defined constructively in that sense has to be continuous, essentially because each finite portion of the result can depend on only a finite portion of the argument.

@RobArthan Admitted I don't know much about constructive and Turning Machines. $\quad$ How about $f(x) = 0 $ if $ x \leq 0 $ and $f(x) = 1$ if $x > 0$? The representation of $x$ would be the sign, followed by the digits of $x$ in decimal places. Granted a positive number that is $ < 10^{-n}$ will take at least $~n$ inputs before it will return a 1, but $x=0$ will take infinitely many inputs in order to return a 0. Is that why that function is not constructive?

@CalvinLin: you are right: determining equality requires an infinite amount of information about the decimal representations, so it's not available when calculating with constructive reals.

@RobArthan You were right. I edited the question. Thanks.

Partial answer: it is possible to start with what I’ll call a “strongly irrational number” $b$ and produce $f(b)$ such that $f(b)$, $f(b) + b$, and $f(b) + \sqrt{2}$ are all strongly irrational. However, it is not clear if any such function can be extended to all of $\mathbb{R}^c$ or $\mathbb{R}^d$.
Definition: $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ are apart if $x < y$ or $y < x$. This is denoted $x \# y$ (think of the symbol as a variation on $\neq$ with an extra diagonal slash).
Definition: $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is said to be a strongly irrational number if for all $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, $x \# q$.
For the purposes of this problem, it is helpful to make another definition: $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-halfcomparable if for all $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, either $x < q$ or $\neg (x < q)$. Note every strongly irrational number is $\mathbb{Q}$-halfcomparable, as is every rational number. It is of interest (but unrelated to the problem) that every $\mathbb{Q}$-halfcomparable number is Cauchy in a canonical way.
Claim: for all sequences $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$-halfcompable numbers, we can explicitly construct a Cauchy real number $y$ which is apart from each $x_n$.
Proof: We define a nested sequence of closed intervals $[a_n, b_n]$ with $a_n, b_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $b_n - a_n = (\frac{1}{3})^n$ recursively as follows. Take $[a_0, b_0] = [0, 1]$. Now suppose given $[a_i, b_i]$. If $\frac{a + b}{2} < x_1$, then let $[a_{i + 1}, b_{i + 1}] = [a_i, \frac{2 a_i + b_i}{3}]$. Otherwise, let $[a_{i + 1}, b_{i + 1}] = [\frac{a_i + 2 b_i}{3}, b_i]$. It is clear that $a$ and $b$ are both Cauchy sequences converging to the same number $y$, the unique real number in $\bigcap\limits_{i} [a_i, b_i]$. Moreover, we see that since $y \in [a_{i + 1}, b_{i + 1}]$, we must by the definition of that interval have $y \# x_i$.
Now in particular, given a number $b$, we can construct a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ whose image is precisely $\mathbb{Q} \cup (\mathbb{Q} - b) \cup (\mathbb{Q} - \sqrt{2})$. When $b$ is strongly irrational, we see that each $x_n$ must be $\mathbb{Q}$-trichotomous. Thus, we may define $f(b)$ to be the $y$ constructed above; then $f(b), f(b) + b$, and $f(b) + \sqrt{2}$ will all be strongly irrational.
So we have defined a function $f$ which takes a strongly irrational $b$ and outputs $f(b)$ such that $f(b), f(b) + b$, and $f(b) + \sqrt{2}$ are all strongly irrational. However, the particular $f$ so constructed cannot be continuously extended to all of $\mathbb{R}$; in particular, the image of $f$ is a subset of the Cantor set, whose closure is not connected. At this time, I do not know whether there is a better construction whose domain can extend to all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Why is being apart different from being different?

@BrunoAndrades $\neg (a # b)$ is equivalent to $a = b$, but that doesn’t mean $a # b$ is equivalent $a \neq b$. The statement that apartness is the same is nonequality is the analytic version of Markov’s Principle, which is not constructively provable but is accepted by some schools of constructivism.
